# Stop fixed positioned header to overlap navigation bar

Tags: css, scroll, css-position

I have something like this:

```
<div id="navigation"></div>
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

The `#header` has `"position:fixed; top: 0;"`, I need it to be this way except when the `#navigation` is visible (not scrolled away), in this case the `#header` should be displayed after the `#navigation`.

Could this be done with pure css?
Or any clean JS solution?

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pomber/v6H4Z/).

Comment: What do you mean by "after the navigation" ? Do you want it on top of it or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a job for the jQuery Waypoints plugin: http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

Using the [sticky element shortcut](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/shortcuts/sticky-elements/):

Just add

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#header').waypoint('sticky');
})
```

and a style for the stuck element

```
#header.stuck {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

Here is the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pomber/v6H4Z/5/)

Comment: Beautiful, that is a very clean JS solution

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using jQuery.

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v6H4Z/4/)

```
//Checks if navigation is visible and sets position of header accordingly
function headerPosition(){
    if($('#navigation').is(':visible')){
        $('#header').css('position', 'static');
    }
    else{
        $('#header').css('position', 'fixed');
    }
}

//Run function to set correct header position
headerPosition();

//Show/Hide navigation to see function in action - not needed for production
$('button').on('click', function(){
   $('#navigation').toggle();
   headerPosition();
});
```